# Get ngFor to repeat data on the basis of name

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a response coming from API as:

```
"leave_types": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "normal_leave",
                "display_name": "Leave",
                "carry_forward_date": "31st Dec 2018",
                "carry_forward_count": 0
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "maternity_leave",
                "display_name": "Maternity\n",
                "carry_forward_date": "31st Dec 2018",
                "carry_forward_count": 0
            }
        ]
```

i want to show this data on hover based on the name, like if i hover on leave i should get data object of leave and if i hover on Maternity i should get data object of maternity/
any idea on how to do it

Comment: Could you show what you currently have as your markup

Comment: I have li
Leave Optional Compassionate Maternity LWP

and i have a div which shows on hover on each of these list items
so i have to match if user has hovered on leave then show leave object

Comment: edit your question with the code please

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
result={"leave_types": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "normal_leave",
                "display_name": "Leave",
                "carry_forward_date": "31st Dec 2018",
                "carry_forward_count": 0
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "maternity_leave",
                "display_name": "Maternity\n",
                "carry_forward_date": "31st Dec 2018",
                "carry_forward_count": 0
            }
        ]}
```

html

```
 <ion-select [(ngModel)]="leavetype" name="leavetype" (ionChange)="changeLeave()">
    <ion-select-option *ngFor="let val of result.leave_types" [value]="val"> {{val.name}}  </ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<li *ngFor=" let leaveTypeAndBalance of leaveTypesAndBalanceList" class="balance-status">
                            {{leaveTypeAndBalance.balance | default: '' }} {{leaveTypeAndBalance.display_name}}
                            <div *ngIf="leaveTypeAndBalance.name == leaveTypesName.lwp" class="relative display-inline">
                                <span class="icon-info-default info-icon"></span>
                                <div class="lwp-hover">This is your current month LWP balance</div>
                            </div>
                            <div *ngIf="leaveTypeAndBalance.name == leaveTypesName.leave"
                                class="relative display-inline">
                                <div class="on-hover" *ngFor="let carryForwardData of carryForwardLeave"
                                    [ngClass]="{'none' : carryForwardData.name !== leaveTypesName.leave}">
                                    <div *ngIf="carryForwardData.name == leaveTypesName.leave">
                                        Carried forward from {{carryForwardData.carry_forward_date}}
                                        <span>{{carryForwardData.carry_forward_count}}</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div *ngIf="leaveTypeAndBalance.name == leaveTypesName.Maternity"
                                [ngClass]="{'none' : carryForwardData.name !== leaveTypesName.leave}"
                                class="relative display-inline">
                                <div class="on-hover" *ngFor="let carryForwardData of carryForwardLeave">
                                    <div *ngIf="carryForwardData.name == leaveTypesName.Maternity">
                                        Carried forward from {{carryForwardData.carry_forward_date}}
                                        <span>{{carryForwardData.carry_forward_count}}</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

just had to make enum and compare the name with them and class

Answer (score 0):

In name.components.ts file add the response in result variable

```
response = { "leave_types": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "normal_leave",
                "display_name": "Leave",
                "carry_forward_date": "31st Dec 2018",
                "carry_forward_count": 0
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "maternity_leave",
                "display_name": "Maternity\n",
                "carry_forward_date": "31st Dec 2018",
                "carry_forward_count": 0
            }
        ]

}
}
```

in name.component.html file, on 'mouseover' get the respected data as Object.

Like.

```
<ul *ngFor="let res of response.leave_types">
  <li (mouseover)="typeValue=res">{{res.display_name}}</li>
</ul>

<ul *ngIf="typeValue">
  <li>{{typeValue.name}}</li>
  <li>{{typeValue.display_name}}</li>
  <li>{{typeValue.carry_forward_date}}</li>
  <li>{{typeValue.carry_forward_count}}</li>
</ul>
```

[Live Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u55kn6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)